# Why adding variables won't work

Tags: python, string, variables, int

I'm making a game where you run your own coffee shop. You choose how many ingredients you want to buy, then it charges you for them as long as they don't cost too much.
Rather than add the variables up as numbers it comes up with this huge number that it 1000s of times larger than the expected value. I have no clue why (I'm fairly new to python so forgive me if it's obvious. This is also my first time using StackOverflow so if I've forgotten to add any info, let me know.)

```
var1 = 11
var 2 = 15
print(str(var1 + var 2))
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: I chose to bu one member of staff, one milk sachet and one set of 50 coffee beans and I got 1.111111111111111e+29 which is far greater then ut should of been....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float((NoStaff * 30))
```

where `NoStaff = '1'` is `'111111111111111111111111111111'` which then gets converted to a number.

You want

```
float(NoStaff) * 30
```

---

Additionally, you may want to address the following logic issues:

- You can buy partial staff members (0.5)
- Your bean count is reset every time you buy new beans
- You get the beans/milk even if they cost too much

Comment: @Monkeybike123 Additionally, you may want to look at some Python style guides - This looks like you're coming Java and the styling is quite different.

Comment: @Monkeybike123 I added some additional logic issues you'll want to address

Comment: Wow thank you I was aware of two of them but the staff count one i had no idea  about! Thanks :)